# Word document and saving as PDF incorrect output

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-reader

I have quite simple word docuemnt that I want to save as PDF. It has few tables and content.
When I save the document I get incorrect tables.. they are some weird white margins that don't appear in the document file. I have tried to recreate the tabels but that doesn't help.

Any help advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Word's own **Save as XPS or PDF** functionality, try a 3rd party PDF printer instead, such as [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php).

Answer (score 0):

Since recreating the tabel can't help, it surely be some hidden characters in your word file, recreate the word file and you will get the right pdf result.